# uncheck Function doesnt work

Tags: javascript

it seem i solve this question myself~

in a simple and stupid way :

Checkall Box

```
var tab = document.getElementById("tbl"); 
var elems = tab.getElementsByTagName("input");
var len = elems.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (tab.checked == elems.checked)
   {
        elems[i].checked = true;
   } 
}
```

UncheckAll Box :

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (tab.checked == elems.checked)
   {
        elems[i].checked = false;
   } 
}
```

Comment: `elems` seems to be an array, array does not have a property `checked`, is `elems` something other than a normal array?

Comment: I think check all works because `tab.checked == elems.checked` are both undefined... SO probably it will always check all...

Comment: how does it "work", what does it do? it looks like you might be trying to set a bunch of checkboxes to the value of one checkbox, like a check-all function? but we can't really tell.

Answer (score 0):

it seem i solve this question myself ~~

Checkall Box

```
var tab = document.getElementById("tbl"); 
var elems = tab.getElementsByTagName("input");
var len = elems.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (tab.checked == elems.checked)
   {
        elems[i].checked = true;
   } 
}
```

}

UncheckAll Box :

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (tab.checked == elems.checked)
   {
        elems[i].checked = false;
   } 
}
```

}